# Given $n$ subsets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ of set $[n]$ that $|A_i|\geq2$ for each subset. Every 2-element set $\{a,b\}\subseteq A_i$ for exactly one $A_i$.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I found cool problem in a book with combinatorial olympiad problems. I was thinking for a while, have some observations but still didn't solve the problem. The statement:

There are given $n$ subsets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ of set $[1..n]$ that $|A_i|\geq2$ for each subset. Every 2-element set $\{a,b\}$ is contained in exactly one $A_i$. Prove that each two subsets $A_i,A_j$ for $1\leq i<j\leq n$ have non-empty intersection.

Observation:
Let's take two subsets $A,B$ and let $a=|A|,b=|B|$. Then, $ab\leq n-2$. If we take any pair $\{a_i,b_j\} \in A\times B$, then in one subset $C$ there can be only one pair from $A\times B$. Otherwise, if we take two pairs $\{a_1,b_2\}\subseteq C$ and $\{a_3,b_4\}\subseteq C$. Then at least one of pairs $a_1,a_3$ and $b_2,b_4$ must have two distinct elements and then we have contradiction that WLOG pair $\{a_1,a_3\}\subseteq A,C$ for some subsets $A$ and $C$. As we have $n-2$ other subsets than $A$ and $B$, by Pigeon Principle $ab\leq n-2$.

Comment: A nice example is $1-2-3,1-4-5,1-6-7,2-4-6,2-5-7,3-4-7,3-5-6$.

Comment: @LuckyLuke Please mention the name of the book.

Comment: @LuckyLuke This is a question-answer site. Where is your question? There is no question-mark anywhere. A problem including some observations or not is not considered as a question in general.

Comment: @Apass.Jack It is polish book "Matematyka olimpijska. Kombinatoryka" by Adam Neugebauer.

Comment: @Apass.Jack the question is how do you prove the statement? Any ideas would be welceomed.

Comment: why is $ab\leq n-2 ?$ something looks very wrong.

Comment: @dezdichado Can you explain what do you mean? I literally gave you the proof of this fact in post.